# No funciona validación de formularios con Javascript simple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```js
$("#guardar").click(function(){

  if(validarFormulario()) {
    alert("exito"); 
  } else {
    alert("error");
  }  

});

//Validar Form
function validarFormulario(){
  $("#txtError_campoNombre").text("");
  $("#txtError_campoPais").text("");

  if($("#campo_nombre").val() == ""){
    $("#txtError_campoNombre").text("Debe ingresar el nombre de la Idea");
    return false;
  }

  if($("#campo_pais").val() == ""){
    $("#txtError_campoPais").text("Debe seleccionar Site");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="campo_nombre">Nombre de la Idea (*)</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
        <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="campo_nombre">        
        </div>
        <span class="span_error" id="txtError_campoNombre"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="campo_pais">Site (*)</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
        <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control" id="campo_pais">
                <option></option>
              </select>        
        </div>
        <span class="span_error" id="txtError_campoPais"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Diego, te sigue dando el error? Veo que quitaste lo de console.log

Comment: @Kenny , ya listo update , si quito console.log y quiero que todos hacer un campo obligatorio

Comment: Disculpa, no entendi tu comentario. Aun tienes el mal funcionamiento? Es que ya probe el codigo y me funciona bien a mi.

Comment: no hay error y nada pero Nombre de la Idea  y site tambien  debe hacer un campo de un formulario obligatorio y utlimo site no funciona un campo obligatorio en js.

Comment: Ya actualice mi respuesta. Espero te sirva. Si resuelve tu problema no olvides marcarla como aceptada para mantener la calidad del sitio. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que tienes un `return` en el primer `if` que impide que el segundo `if` se ejecute, por lo tanto, nunca le permites a `JQuery` desplegar el mensaje. Lo que puedes hacer es tener una variable donde almacenar el resultado y retornarla hasta de último.

```
function validarFormulario(){
  var resultado = true;

  $("#txtError_campoNombre").text("");
  $("#txtError_campoPais").text("");

   if($("#campo_nombre").val() == ""){
       $("#txtError_campoNombre").text("Debe ingresar el nombre de la Idea");
       resultado = false;
    }

    if($("#campo_pais").val() == ""){
        $("#txtError_campoPais").text("Debe seleccionar Site");
        resultado = false;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

---

P.D. Siempre puedes escribir texto (en `Paint`?) en vez de dibujarlo. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Estimado

Veo que no has agregado la etiqueta  y tampoco un submit. Asumiendo que las tienes debes realizar la siguiente actualización en la etiqueta form...onsubmit, ejemplo:

```
   <form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return validarFormulario()">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            ......
        </div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Estoy agregando un botón submit para que puedas probarlo.
Saludos